# Dell XPS 13 (9343) Developer Edition with Ubuntu 14.04 does not boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, live-usb, boot-repair

Wanted to update my Dell XPS 13 to 16.04 from 14.04 using the command:

```
update-manager -d
```

In between got this error :

> Could not install 'sysv-rc'
>
> The upgrade will continue but the 'sysv-rc' package may not be in a working state. Please consider submitting a bug report about it.

And after this machine got blank screen. I hard restart. No UI. I try do a factory reset by going to Dell Recovery. I get error:

> unable to find a medium containing a live file system

I bring out my recovery usb drive and reboot to it  (UEFI : ). I get error:

> unable to find a medium containing a live file system

I change BIOS mode to legacy.
I try Legacy Boot : Usb Storage Drive. I get error :

> no system disk. Press any key to reboot

And after this restart I’m not even able to reboot to command prompt. It comes to No Boot Device Found. Press any Key to continue.

I prepare a 16.04 Ubuntu live usb drive and boot from the usb drive. The machine has booted to the usb drive, but stuck in blank screen with a cursor blinking. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrote the iso file to USB stick right way ?

I suggest you to have an 4GB USB drive and use dd command.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media#Using_dd

You can use the same way.